# SIGABRT after clean project xcode

Tags: uiviewcontroller, interface-builder

My code was working fine for days and weeks of code changes and running on my iPhone 5.0 simulator until I cleaned it.

Now it dies on this line `[window addSubview:self.viewController.view];`

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

    [self.window addSubview:self.viewController.view];   // dies here
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

`self.viewController` exists, but `self.viewController.view` does not.

[image: <code>self.viewController.view</code> does not exist]

EDIT to add my `AppDelegate.h`:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class MainMenu;

@interface yomikakiAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
    UIWindow *window;
    MainMenu *viewController;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet MainMenu *viewController;

@end
```

I think IB must have lost a connection somewhere, but I'm not sure how to rewire it.

I made my MainMenu.xib Referencing Outlet view be File's Owner, but that didn't fix it.

[image: This didn't help but I hoped it would!!]

How can I get my viewController get its view back?

EDIT to add screenshot of Identity Inspector of my nib file:

[image: screenshot of .xib File's Owner Identity Inspector]

Comment: modify your code to [self.window addSubview:viewController.view];

Comment: oh my!  How could it at worked before?

Comment: I added it but it still crashes in the same point.  (N.B. I also removed the Referencing Outlet connection I had created trying to solve this issue)

Comment: I've re-re-connected the view to File's Owner in my nib, and added "self" as RKK suggested, but it still crashes in the same place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello why are you doing this?

`[window addSubview:self.viewController.view];`

Try this

`[self.window addSubview:self.viewController.view];`
 `[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];`
 `return YES;`

The File Owner has to be linked to the View of the ViewController.

Comment: Yes, per RKK's comment I added "self" to that line of code.  I've modified my question to reflect that, but the app still crashes on the line indicated in my question.   I also have linked File Owner to the view of the view controller.

Comment: Is the your App Delegate calling the correct ViewController? Did you import viewController in the AppDelegate .h?

Comment: Maybe a duplicate ViewController in your project Folder?

Comment: Well, I have three classes that extend UIViewController, but they all have different names, and the AppDelegate only refers to MainMenu.   MainMenu calls the others when they're needed.

Comment: See the last line of GDB: self.viewController.view                There is no member named view, are you sure the view in the viewController is correctly linked? Are you using a Xib for the viewController? If yes in the Xib of viewController, under File Owner-->Show Identity Inspector.                                        Is viewController inserted under Class name?

Comment: @AlbrahimZ sorry I had to sleep but I'm awake again.  In code, there is no `view` in my ViewController at all; I'm using a nib file.  The correct ViewController is listed under Class name.  I'll post screenshot of xib and Identity Inspector.

Comment: This type of problem also happen with me... i didn't understand still why this happen??? But when i restart my PC then this problem was removed.

Comment: @Thunder Rabbit, ok so if you are using a nib file(xib), can you check in your viewController, if the correct class name is being assigned?

Comment: @Thunder Rabbit Got it fixed? well View Controllers shouldn't never be renamed directly in Xcode(or in the project folder), the best way to change name to a view controller, is deleting it and creating a new one(obviously checking in the project folder that the view controller has been deleted), then you can assign the same name to the view controller,or a new name !) Have a good day :)

Comment: yep, I got it fixed!  Thanks for your help and your tip on how to rename UIViewControllers.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

*Thou shalt not rename thy UIViewControllers.*

A couple weeks ago I renamed my original firstProjectViewController to be MainMenu, allowing its name to fit in with FooMenu and BarMenu, the names of its brethren.

I don't know why the project kept compiling at that time, but the problem didn't become apparent until I cleaned my code a couple nights ago.

So I'm choosing the answer that would be right in a high percent of the cases, but to solve it for myself, I needed to un-change every occurrence of "MainMenu" back to "firstProjectViewController."